# Is there a way to access a child method directly (without casting) from an extended TreeItem?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I tried to reduce as much as possible my piece of code to illustrate my question. So...

This code, does not "do" anything. My point is just to ask if it would be possible to get access to the method `needsCasting()` **without** the casting in following example ?

It for sure has to do with what compiler "sees", and what is for him the difference between `CustomTreeItem` and it's parent `TreeItem<Dummy>`.

Of what my research ended up with, is that the 'hidden' list children inside the `TreeItem` class is of `TreeItem<Dummy>`, and not `CustomTreeItem`, but my question stays whole :
"Is there a way to access a child method directly (without casting) ?"

Here comes the example :

```
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableRow;

public class CastingQuestion {

    public class Dummy extends TreeTableRow<Dummy> {

    }

    public final class CustomTreeItem extends TreeItem<Dummy> {

        private void needsCasting() {
            System.out.println("Hello world");
        }

        public void listChildren() {
            for (TreeItem<Dummy> item : getChildren()) {
                ((CustomTreeItem) item).needsCasting();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If we can guarantee that `getChildren()` only returns a `List<CustomTreeItem>`, then `getChildren()` should return a `List<CustomTreeItem>` or a `List<? extends CustomTreeitem>` instead of a `TreeItem<Dummy>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable of type `TreeItem<Dummy>`, you cannot access a method or property on it that is specific to `CustomTreeItem` without first casting it to a `CustomTreeItem` object. This is because all the compiler knows is that the variable is of type `TreeItem<Dummy>` which isn't necessarily going to be a `CustomTreeItem`.

Say I had two classes, `TreeItemA` and `TreeItemB` - both subclasses of (extending from) `TreeItem<Dummy>`. And I have a variable of type `TreeItem<Dummy>`.

```
TreeItem<Dummy> item;
```

This variable could be an instance of `TreeItemA` or `TreeItemB`:

```
item = new TreeItemA(); //valid assignment
item = new TreeItemB(); //valid assignment
```

Therefore, you can only access properties or methods of the variable that are in the base `TreeItem` class if you don't cast down to a subclass - it all depends on the type of the variable you are working with.

Edit: It is worth noting that the `getChildren()` method you are calling in `CustomTreeItem` returns `ObservableList<TreeItem<T>>` (according to default `TreeItem` implementation). This means that when you iterate over the list returned from `getChildren()`, each element will be of the type `TreeItem<Dummy>`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: It is against OOP to call method of child classes.

Answer to you question is **No**. Parent classes does not know your Child class methods.